# Why isn't my Ginkgo biloba growing any leaves even though it's already June?

Tags: trees, growth

I have a couple of [Ginkgos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginkgo_biloba). Last year I got them by mail, there were already yellow leaves when I got them. They went to sleep around October or November. This year it is already June and they have nothing, no leaves, nothing, and they are not growing any at all. When I check the trunk it looks healthy and green. They don't look dry or sick but there is not one leaf.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't know anything about Ginkgos, but the people who do know those trees will probably need you to supply a little more info. Like what part of the world you are in, and what sort of weather you have been having lately.

Comment: Where you are is important to know, but also very important is what you did with them when you received them - did you plant them in the ground and keep them well watered? Or did you pot them up in good potting soil? Do you have bad winter freezes?

Comment: So, did the tree eventually leaf out, or did it die?

Answer (score 3):

Wait.

*The trunk is heathy and green,* so the tree is apparently alive.

You can't do much for it putting out leaves other than wait for it to do that, so do that.

If it doesn't do that, at some point it will also stop looking healthy and green at the trunk and you'll know it's dead. For now, assume it's dormant and don't fuss too much about it. If it showed up with leaves out before planting last year it may have some overall stress and adaptation issues it needs to work though on its own schedule.

I just found green buds on two (apple) grafts I had nearly given up on for this year - patience can be a good thing.